# Android Caching App data when app is deleted

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, sqlite-net

I have created an C# Xamarin Android application that saves data to a SQLite database (sqlite-net nuget package). The database path is `System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "AppName.db")`
When the app is deleted, and reinstalled using Visual Studio 2019 (haven't used any other methods), The data from the application stays.

However, the data that returns is an old set of data. I can clear the data from the database from within the app. Uninstall then reinstall and the data returns. Have also gone into App Settings and cleared cache and app files. The install does not include any SQLite files. Or any hard coded data.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have `android:allowBackup` set to true?

Comment: @SushiHangover I did apparently have allowBackup to true. Do you want to put that as an answer so i can accept it?